# How to convert a List to Data Frame, but removing the internal List structure?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

It sounds simple, but I have many problems trying to convert a List to Data Frame.
I did it with the **as.data.frame** function and it works, but when I use the **str** function the internal structure still remains with the **List** structure. And I would like to select a specific column to work in it.

There is some easy way to convert a List to Data Frame, but with a new data frame structure? 
I have tryied also unlisting my List into a matrix but I lose the colnames and rownames, and I have to put it again manually.

For example that is my **List**, and I would like to use and plot the ***mystats$p.value*** column:

```
library(gtools)
 x <- rnorm(100, sd=1)
 y <- rnorm(100, sd =2)

mystats <- t(running(x, y, fun = cor.test, width=5, by=5))
```

Thanks

Comment: If the `str` says that it is a list, then the `as.data.frame` function did not work and you still have a list. Please add more details and/or a reproducible example.

Comment: I have already added an example, I would like to have the same result  as the @LucaBraglia's answer, but with this type of List generated with running()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If and only if it's a list of `data.frame`s you can use do.call

```
al <- split(airquality, airquality$Month)
sapply(al, class)
same.airquality <- do.call(rbind, al)
```

Here the list elements have the *same structure of columns* (for list that "splits" different variables across list elements, each the same `nrow`), you can use

```
do.call(cbind, another.list)
```

Finally (but not tested) with this approach you `could` try package `abind`

**EDIT**

After the example provided i understand a little more your setting: you shoud sanitize a bit the call to `cor.test` because with `running` it messes data a bit (currently you are trying to put a list, a complex data structure, in a matrix like object)

```
foobar <- function(x,y) {
    my.test <- cor.test(x,y)

    ## look at values returned by names(cor.test) or ?cor.test for
    ## which object you can export                                      

    c(my.test$statistic, my.test$p.value, my.test$conf.int)

}

## mystats is a matrix                                                          
mystats <- as.data.frame(t(running(x, y, fun = foobar, width=5, by=5)))
names(mystats) <- c("statistic", "p.value", "low.ci", "up.ci")
mystats$p.value
```

If you have multiple objects like this one, eg

```
mystats$row <- row.names(mystats)
mystats$rep <- 1
row.names(mystats) <- NULL                                          
mystats2 <- mystats
mystats2$rep <- 2
asd <- list(mystats, mystats2)
foo <- do.call("rbind", asd )
foo
foo$p.value
```

HTH

Comment: thanks @LucaBraglia that is exactly the result that I need but with the List example that I have added in my question.